# Provide a scrollbar for D3 widget

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a D3 collapsible tree which works as expected

```js
var data = [
    { "name" : "Level 2: A", "parent":"Top Level" },
    { "name" : "Top Level", "parent":"null" },
    { "name" : "Son of A", "parent":"Level 2: A" },
    { "name" : "Daughter of A", "parent":"Level 2: A" },
    { "name" : "Level 2: B", "parent":"Top Level" }
    ];

var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
 map[node.name] = node;
 return map;
}, {});

var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
 // add to parent
 var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
 if (parent) {
  // create child array if it doesn't exist
  (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
   // add node to child array
   .push(node);
 } else {
  // parent is null or missing
  treeData.push(node);
 }
});

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 // width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 // height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
    width = 300 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var i = 0;
var duration = 1000;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="tree"></div>
</body>
```

Please refer to the lines where width and height are set (commented out right now for this example)

```
 // width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
// height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

This width and height gives enough space for the widget to display, so everything works fine.

However, there are some scenarios where the space is limited on the page, or the tree has several nodes that cannot fit in the allocated space.

I have tried to reproduce this scenario by reducing the width and height

```
width = 300 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

When this happens, part of the tree is cut off and there is no way for the user to look at the hidden portions of the tree.

Is there a way to provide a scrollbar when the height or width of the tree goes beyond the allocated height or width?

Any other suggestions to provide a way for users to look at the missing data are also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: However, there are some scenarios where the space is limited on the page, or the tree has several nodes that cannot fit in the allocated space. What kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcgmxff0/2/

Put width and height to your tree element

```
#tree {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this CSS, and there seems to be some scrollbar but that does not work. It does not provide the ability to scroll and see the hidden parts of the tree. In my example above, if you were to increase the width and height, the additional nodes of the tree would appear.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle, you can resize the screen to whatever size you want and still works. Probably I'm not understanding your question)) @kayasa

Comment: I did check the fiddle, however, it did not have the CSS you have mentioned above. So, I just added the CSS, which gives a scrollbar but there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: This works fine, as width and height are increased to 960 and 500. However, if I were to reduce this to 300 and 300 (http://jsfiddle.net/6Ldad16n/4/), part of the tree is hidden. This could happen when there are lots of other widgets on the page, or the tree is a big one and does not fit into the allocated space.

Comment: gotcha just a min @kayasa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78055/discussion-between-said-kholov-and-kayasa).